# Cell Color detection issue when converting jupyter notebook to pdf

Tags: pdf, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, nbconvert

when i convert jupyter notebook to pdf there is no cell color of In and Out detected. More over tables do not have borders. Can anyone please guide me to convert to pdf with these features?

[image: pdf output screeshot]